# How long should Olympus EP-5 warranty repair take?

Tags: repair, olympus

My EP-5 (purchased July 2013 in the US) developed a problem where it occasionally would not turn on. I brought it back to the photography store I purchased it from and they sent it to Olympus for repair. That was four weeks ago. I called to check on it today and they said they hadn't heard from Olympus. I expressed frustration that the camera had been out of my hands for four weeks, but they said this was normal and there was nothing they could do.

Is this really normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally 4 weeks for a repair turn-around is minimal. The camera has to be sent, wait to be seen, order the parts, perform the repair, test and ship it back. In many cases, complex parts may need equipment which is not available locally and the camera has to take a trip to Asia and back. That makes it spend 3 or more weeks in transport alone.

Sorry but you will have to be patient. I learned my lesson once after one of my repairs took 16 weeks. Always have a backup camera and back-up lenses for your most common uses. They do not have to be exact duplicates but I find it helps greatly since you immediately know how to use your backup camera and lens.